# Push to Heroku No Changes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku, push

I have been able to successfully push my files earlier in the day with changes showing up. However now when I have made changes, and done the push the changes don't show up on Heroku, despite thee console indicating that everything happened successfully, here is my heroku log:
(I should add when I run localhost the latest changes are there)

```
2011-11-12T03:00:56+00:00 app[web.1]: cache: [GET /users/sign_up] miss
2011-11-12T03:00:56+00:00 heroku[router]: GET severe-dawn-7397.heroku.com/users/sign_up dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=2357ms status=200 bytes=2305
2011-11-12T03:00:56+00:00 heroku[nginx]: 209.6.52.33 - - [11/Nov/2011:19:00:56 -0800] "GET /users/sign_up HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/535.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/15.0.874.106 Safari/535.2" severe-dawn-7397.heroku.com
2011-11-12T03:00:56+00:00 heroku[router]: GET severe-dawn-7397.heroku.com/assets/application-e0d2fd57e0269815001b4bd485afdf68.css dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=2ms status=200 bytes=874
2011-11-12T03:00:56+00:00 app[web.1]: cache: [GET /assets/application-e0d2fd57e0269815001b4bd485afdf68.css] miss
2011-11-12T03:00:56+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2011-11-12T03:00:56+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2011-11-12T03:00:56+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/assets/web-app-theme/base-6cb77531216dc7b8d6b75dc696817e63.css" for 209.6.52.33 at 2011-11-11 19:00:56 -0800
2011-11-12T03:00:56+00:00 app[web.1]: cache: [GET /assets/web-app-theme/base-6cb77531216dc7b8d6b75dc696817e63.css] miss, store
2011-11-12T03:00:56+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2011-11-12T03:00:56+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2011-11-12T03:00:56+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/assets/web-app-theme/override.css" for 209.6.52.33 at 2011-11-11 19:00:56 -0800
2011-11-12T03:00:56+00:00 heroku[nginx]: 209.6.52.33 - - [11/Nov/2011:19:00:56 -0800] "GET /assets/application-e0d2fd57e0269815001b4bd485afdf68.css HTTP/1.1" 200 874 "http://severe-dawn-7397.heroku.com/users/sign_up" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/535.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/15.0.874.106 Safari/535.2" severe-dawn-7397.heroku.com
2011-11-12T03:00:56+00:00 heroku[nginx]: 209.6.52.33 - - [11/Nov/2011:19:00:56 -0800] "GET /assets/web-app-theme/base-6cb77531216dc7b8d6b75dc696817e63.css HTTP/1.1" 200 1552 "http://severe-dawn-7397.heroku.com/users/sign_up" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/535.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/15.0.874.106 Safari/535.2" severe-dawn-7397.heroku.com
2011-11-12T03:00:56+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2011-11-12T03:00:56+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/web-app-theme/override.css"):
2011-11-12T03:00:56+00:00 app[web.1]:   
2011-11-12T03:00:56+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2011-11-12T03:00:56+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2011-11-12T03:00:56+00:00 app[web.1]: cache: [GET /assets/web-app-theme/override.css] miss
2011-11-12T03:00:56+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2011-11-12T03:00:56+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2011-11-12T03:00:56+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/assets/web-app-theme/themes/activo/style-9be8c35c1a02f88029189a304317a143.css" for 209.6.52.33 at 2011-11-11 19:00:56 -0800
2011-11-12T03:00:56+00:00 heroku[router]: GET severe-dawn-7397.heroku.com/assets/web-app-theme/base-6cb77531216dc7b8d6b75dc696817e63.css dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=10ms status=200 bytes=6181
2011-11-12T03:00:56+00:00 app[web.1]: cache: [GET /assets/web-app-theme/themes/activo/style-9be8c35c1a02f88029189a304317a143.css] miss, store
2011-11-12T03:00:56+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2011-11-12T03:00:56+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2011-11-12T03:00:56+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/assets/defaults.js" for 209.6.52.33 at 2011-11-11 19:00:56 -0800
2011-11-12T03:00:56+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2011-11-12T03:00:56+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/defaults.js"):
2011-11-12T03:00:56+00:00 app[web.1]:   
2011-11-12T03:00:56+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2011-11-12T03:00:56+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2011-11-12T03:00:56+00:00 app[web.1]: cache: [GET /assets/defaults.js] miss
2011-11-12T03:00:56+00:00 heroku[router]: GET severe-dawn-7397.heroku.com/assets/web-app-theme/themes/activo/style-9be8c35c1a02f88029189a304317a143.css dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=26ms status=200 bytes=18335
2011-11-12T03:00:56+00:00 heroku[router]: GET severe-dawn-7397.heroku.com/assets/defaults.js dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=24ms status=404 bytes=728
2011-11-12T03:00:56+00:00 heroku[nginx]: 209.6.52.33 - - [11/Nov/2011:19:00:56 -0800] "GET /assets/web-app-theme/override.css HTTP/1.1" 404 728 "http://severe-dawn-7397.heroku.com/users/sign_up" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/535.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/15.0.874.106 Safari/535.2" severe-dawn-7397.heroku.com
2011-11-12T03:00:56+00:00 heroku[nginx]: 209.6.52.33 - - [11/Nov/2011:19:00:56 -0800] "GET /assets/defaults.js HTTP/1.1" 404 728 "http://severe-dawn-7397.heroku.com/users/sign_up" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/535.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/15.0.874.106 Safari/535.2" severe-dawn-7397.heroku.com
2011-11-12T03:00:56+00:00 heroku[nginx]: 209.6.52.33 - - [11/Nov/2011:19:00:56 -0800] "GET /assets/web-app-theme/themes/activo/style-9be8c35c1a02f88029189a304317a143.css HTTP/1.1" 200 3619 "http://severe-dawn-7397.heroku.com/users/sign_up" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/535.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/15.0.874.106 Safari/535.2" severe-dawn-7397.heroku.com
2011-11-12T03:00:56+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2011-11-12T03:00:56+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2011-11-12T03:00:56+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/assets/web-app-theme/themes/activo/fonts/museosans_500-webfont.woff" for 209.6.52.33 at 2011-11-11 19:00:56 -0800
2011-11-12T03:00:56+00:00 heroku[router]: GET severe-dawn-7397.heroku.com/assets/web-app-theme/themes/activo/fonts/museosans_500-webfont.woff dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=11ms status=200 bytes=26496
2011-11-12T03:00:56+00:00 app[web.1]: cache: [GET /assets/web-app-theme/themes/activo/fonts/museosans_500-webfont.woff] miss, store
2011-11-12T03:00:56+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2011-11-12T03:00:56+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2011-11-12T03:00:56+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/assets/web-app-theme/themes/activo/fonts/museo700-regular-webfont.woff" for 209.6.52.33 at 2011-11-11 19:00:56 -0800
2011-11-12T03:00:56+00:00 heroku[nginx]: 209.6.52.33 - - [11/Nov/2011:19:00:56 -0800] "GET /assets/web-app-theme/themes/activo/fonts/museosans_500-webfont.woff HTTP/1.1" 200 26496 "http://severe-dawn-7397.her

2011-11-12T03:00:56+00:00 heroku[router]: GET severe-dawn-7397.heroku.com/assets/web-app-theme/themes/activo/fonts/museo700-regular-webfont.woff dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=13ms status=200 bytes=28204
2011-11-12T03:00:56+00:00 app[web.1]: cache: [GET /assets/web-app-theme/themes/activo/fonts/museo700-regular-webfont.woff] miss, store
2011-11-12T03:00:56+00:00 heroku[nginx]: 209.6.52.33 - - [11/Nov/2011:19:00:56 -0800] "GET /assets/web-app-theme/themes/activo/fonts/museo700-regular-webfont.woff HTTP/1.1" 200 28204 "http://severe-dawn-7397.heroku.com/users/sign_up" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/535.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/15.0.874.106 Safari/535.2" severe-dawn-7397.heroku.com
2011-11-12T03:01:02+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2011-11-12T03:01:02+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2011-11-12T03:01:02+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/users/sign_up" for 209.6.52.33 at 2011-11-11 19:01:02 -0800
2011-11-12T03:01:02+00:00 app[web.1]:   Processing by RegistrationsController#new as HTML
2011-11-12T03:01:02+00:00 app[web.1]: Rendered devise/shared/_links.erb (0.3ms)
2011-11-12T03:01:02+00:00 app[web.1]: Rendered registrations/new.html.erb within layouts/application (3.1ms)
2011-11-12T03:01:02+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 9ms (Views: 8.3ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
2011-11-12T03:01:02+00:00 app[web.1]: cache: [GET /users/sign_up] miss
2011-11-12T03:01:02+00:00 heroku[router]: GET severe-dawn-7397.heroku.com/users/sign_up dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=14ms status=200 bytes=2305
2011-11-12T03:01:02+00:00 heroku[nginx]: 209.6.52.33 - - [11/Nov/2011:19:01:02 -0800] "GET /users/sign_up HTTP/1.1" 200 905 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/535.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/15.0.874.106 Safari/535.2" severe-dawn-7397.heroku.com
2011-11-12T03:01:02+00:00 app[web.1]: cache: [GET /assets/application-e0d2fd57e0269815001b4bd485afdf68.css] miss
2011-11-12T03:01:02+00:00 heroku[nginx]: 209.6.52.33 - - [11/Nov/2011:19:01:02 -0800] "GET /assets/web-app-theme/base-6cb77531216dc7b8d6b75dc696817e63.css HTTP/1.1" 200 1546 "http://severe-dawn-7397.heroku.com/users/sign_up" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/535.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/15.0.874.106 Safari/535.2" severe-dawn-7397.heroku.com
2011-11-12T03:01:02+00:00 heroku[nginx]: 209.6.52.33 - - [11/Nov/2011:19:01:02 -0800] "GET /assets/web-app-theme/themes/activo/style-9be8c35c1a02f88029189a304317a143.css HTTP/1.1" 200 3591 "http://severe-dawn-7397.heroku.com/users/sign_up" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/535.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/15.0.874.106 Safari/535.2" severe-dawn-7397.heroku.com
2011-11-12T03:01:02+00:00 heroku[nginx]: 209.6.52.33 - - [11/Nov/2011:19:01:02 -0800] "GET /assets/application-e0d2fd57e0269815001b4bd485afdf68.css HTTP/1.1" 200 874 "http://severe-dawn-7397.heroku.com/users/sign_up" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/535.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/15.0.874.106 Safari/535.2" severe-dawn-7397.heroku.com
2011-11-12T03:01:02+00:00 heroku[router]: GET severe-dawn-7397.heroku.com/assets/application-e0d2fd57e0269815001b4bd485afdf68.css dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=7ms status=200 bytes=874
2011-11-12T03:01:02+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2011-11-12T03:01:02+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2011-11-12T03:01:02+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/assets/web-app-theme/override.css" for 209.6.52.33 at 2011-11-11 19:01:02 -0800
2011-11-12T03:01:02+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2011-11-12T03:01:02+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/web-app-theme/override.css"):
2011-11-12T03:01:02+00:00 app[web.1]:   
2011-11-12T03:01:02+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2011-11-12T03:01:02+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2011-11-12T03:01:02+00:00 app[web.1]: cache: [GET /assets/web-app-theme/override.css] miss
2011-11-12T03:01:02+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2011-11-12T03:01:02+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2011-11-12T03:01:02+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/assets/defaults.js" for 209.6.52.33 at 2011-11-11 19:01:02 -0800
2011-11-12T03:01:02+00:00 heroku[router]: GET severe-dawn-7397.heroku.com/assets/web-app-theme/override.css dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=6ms status=404 bytes=728
2011-11-12T03:01:02+00:00 heroku[nginx]: 209.6.52.33 - - [11/Nov/2011:19:01:02 -0800] "GET /assets/web-app-theme/override.css HTTP/1.1" 404 728 "http://severe-dawn-7397.heroku.com/users/sign_up" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/535.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/15.0.874.106 Safari/535.2" severe-dawn-7397.heroku.com
2011-11-12T03:01:02+00:00 heroku[router]: GET severe-dawn-7397.heroku.com/assets/defaults.js dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=4ms status=404 bytes=728
2011-11-12T03:01:02+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2011-11-12T03:01:02+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/defaults.js"):
2011-11-12T03:01:02+00:00 app[web.1]:   
2011-11-12T03:01:02+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2011-11-12T03:01:02+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2011-11-12T03:01:02+00:00 app[web.1]: cache: [GET /assets/defaults.js] miss
2011-11-12T03:01:03+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2011-11-12T03:01:03+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2011-11-12T03:01:03+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/assets/web-app-theme/themes/activo/fonts/museo700-regular-webfont.woff" for 209.6.52.33 at 2011-11-11 19:01:03 -0800
2011-11-12T03:01:03+00:00 app[web.1]: cache: [GET /assets/web-app-theme/themes/activo/fonts/museo700-regular-webfont.woff] stale, valid, store
2011-11-12T03:01:03+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2011-11-12T03:01:03+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2011-11-12T03:01:03+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/assets/web-app-theme/themes/activo/fonts/museosans_500-webfont.woff" for 209.6.52.33 at 2011-11-11 19:01:03 -0800
2011-11-12T03:01:03+00:00 app[web.1]: cache: [GET /assets/web-app-theme/themes/activo/fonts/museosans_500-webfont.woff] stale, valid, store
2011-11-12T03:01:03+00:00 heroku[router]: GET severe-dawn-7397.heroku.com/assets/web-app-theme/themes/activo/fonts/museosans_500-webfont.woff dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=10ms status=200 bytes=26496
2011-11-12T03:01:03+00:00 heroku[nginx]: 209.6.52.33 - - [11/Nov/2011:19:01:03 -0800] "GET /assets/web-app-theme/themes/activo/fonts/museo700-regular-webfont.woff HTTP/1.1" 200 28204 "http://severe-dawn-7397.heroku.com/users/sign_up" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/535.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/15.0.874.106 Safari/535.2" severe-dawn-7397.heroku.com
2011-11-12T03:01:03+00:00 app[web.1]: cache: [GET /favicon.ico] miss
2011-11-12T03:01:03+00:00 heroku[nginx]: 209.6.52.33 - - [11/Nov/2011:19:01:03 -0800] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/535.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/15.0.874.106 Safari/535.2" severe-dawn-7397.heroku.com
2011-11-12T03:01:03+00:00 heroku[router]: GET severe-dawn-7397.heroku.com/favicon.ico dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=3ms status=200 bytes=0
```

Comment: Run command `heroku restart --app YOUR_APP_NAME` and check again.

Comment: are you pushing a branch perhaps?

Comment: That's probably the problem because:


    git commit -a -m "fix yourself"
    # On branch production
    nothing to commit (working directory clean)

Any idea on how to fix it then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're on a local branch that is not MASTER then to push to heroku you need to do;

```
git push heroku production:master
```

Heroku only deploys the master branch so you have to push your local branch (ie production) into the master branch on Heroku. Obviously replace 'heroku' in this with whatever you refer to your heroku remote as.

Comment: Thanks a lot! that seemed to have resolved the pushing problem but opened another error, since unrelated I made a new question. But thanks for that explanation.